# MySQL Foreign Key constraint fails for multiple keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Hi I am creating several tables some of which have multiple keys linking to the same table. When I try to create the foreign key links I am given:

```
errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
```

Here are the tables I am creating:

```
create table EventFeed (
 EventFeedID integer auto_increment not null,
 EventName varchar(100),
 EventTime Timestamp,
 EventLocation varchar(100),
 primary key (EventFeedID)
);

create table Calendar (
 MyEventID integer auto_increment not null,
 EventFeedID integer,
 EventName varchar(100),
 EventTime Timestamp,
 EventLocation varchar(100),
 AttendeeID varchar(100),
 primary key (MyEventID),
 foreign key (EventFeedID) references EventFeed (EventFeedID),
 foreign key (EventName) references EventFeed (EventName),
 foreign key (EventTime) references EventFeed (EventTime),
 foreign key (EventLocation) references EventFeed (EventLocation),
 foreign key (AttendeeID) references Users (UserID)
);
```

The error seems to be coming from the foreign keys in the 'Calendar' table however some of my other tables have used similar foreign keys and given no errors

can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you try 'FOREIGN KEY (X , Y) REFERENCES EventFeed(x, y)'

Comment: Also check AttendeeID is it the same type as Users.UserID ?

Comment: Check: [13.1.18.3 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints :: Foreign keys definitions are subject to the following conditions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eec9436/1).

Comment: It still gives the same error when I try the  'FOREIGN KEY (X , Y) REFERENCES EventFeed(x, y)' and the AttendeeID is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a foreign key on the column which is a non-primary key except the columns with unique constraint. So you have to make EventName, EventTime, etc unique if you want it to be referred by a foreign key.

You can check here at: [Technet Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

You can see this fiddle for working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05663

Comment: @randomer I hope that you know that the values in column with unique constraint cannot be repeated and as per your table attributes such as EventTime, EventLocation etc will be repeated hence do not apply unique constraint to them. Instead if you you want the such details to be inserted automatically you can fetch it with the help of primary key of EventFeed and insert it along with user supplied values for other attributes.